# Writing expressions in terms of only sine

Tags: trigonometry

If I were to do this without these formulas, I would pull out a number that made both of the numbers(like (sqrt(3))/2 and 1/2) in the picture would be something that I could get a sine and cosine that works for them. This formula for K gives me this number I should pull out but how? Can someone explain why the formula for K is the number that you should pull out to make the numbers work for a cosine and sine insertion?

[IMG][http://i57.tinypic.com/2n1gwty.jpg[/IMG]](http://i57.tinypic.com/2n1gwty.jpg%5b/IMG%5d)

Comment: You mean, why $k = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}$?

Comment: The method makes use of the Pythagorean Identity $ \ \sin^2 x \ + \ \cos^2 x \ = \ 1 \ $ .  If you just have coefficients $ \ A \ \ \text{and} \ \ B \ $ , dividing through by $ \ \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \ $ produces new coefficients which satisfy the Identity, and thus "behave" like the sine and cosine of some angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to adjust the coefficients so that the sum of their squares is $1$. That makes them the sine and cosine of some angle. So multiply and divide by the square root of the sum of their squares:
$$a\sin t + b\cos t=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin t +\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos t\right)
$$
$$=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\sin t\cos \phi +\cos t\sin \phi\right)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(t+\phi)$$
where $\phi$ is the angle with $(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)=(a/\sqrt{a^2+b^2},b/\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$. This is possible because 
$$\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2 =\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}=1$$
so the adjusted coefficients are the coordinates of a point on the unit circle.

Comment: Why would you do this though? (multiply and divide by K)

Comment: You are scaling the point $(a,b)$ along the line through it and the origin to get a point that is exactly at a distance of $1$ from the origin. That lets you read the cosine and sine off of the coordinates of the point on the unit circle. The angle hasn't changed,just the distance from the origin. See?

Comment: If you wanted to, you could do this with any couple of pairs of numbers: $au+bv =\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}u +\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}v)$, then repeat for the other pair to get $au+bv = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{u^2+v^2}(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}})$. This can be written $au+bv =\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\sin(\phi +\psi)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look at this in the morning, I think I get it but I'm just too tired...

Comment: Oh I see, so this can also be explained using right triangles. The reason the "K" is in the mix is because the two functions share the r in y/r and x/r. So this gets it to be the sine of something and the cosine of something. Right??

Comment: Bingo${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Well, only if the numbers you get are on [-1,1]?

Comment: It's always true. That's what the operation does.Only exception is if the entire expression is identically zero, in which case you can't write it in the desired form anyway.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking, well what if it is 100 for a and 350 for b or something big like that but the denominator would be the perfect r for the triangle anyway.